# Re-using HttpClient but with a different Timeout setting per request?

Tags: .net, dotnet-httpclient

In order to reuse open TCP connections with `HttpClient` you have to share a single instance for all requests.

This means that we *cannot* simply instantiate `HttpClient` with different settings (e.g. timeout or headers).

How can we share the connections and use different settings at the same time? This was very easy, in fact the default, with the older `HttpWebRequest` and `WebClient` infrastructure.

Note, that simply setting `HttpClient.Timeout` before making a request is not thread safe and would not work in a concurrent application (e.g. an ASP.NET web site).

Comment: Which settings are you looking to vary on the same instance other than `Timeout`? Things like headers are settable per request, and varying `BaseAddress` doesn't make much sense because each different one will require a new connection anyway. Practically speaking, `Timeout` might be the _only_ property you'd want to vary on the same instance. I can show you how to use a different timeout per request if that answers the question.

Comment: @ToddMenier that's a good point. That would answer the question, yes!

Comment: It should be clarified that reusing `HttpClient` means you are reusing a _single_ TCP connection. There is no "pooling" involved here.

Comment: @ToddMenier I'm pretty sure that's not true. This also would imply that parallel requests on the same HttpClient object are not executed in parallel which I am quite sure as well is not the case.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Under the hood, `HttpClient` just uses a cancellation token to implement the timeout behavior. You can do the same directly if you want to vary it per request:

```
using var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
cts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
await httpClient.GetAsync("http://www.google.com", cts.Token);
```

Note that the default timeout for `HttpClient` is 100 seconds, and the request will still be canceled at that point even if you've set a higher value at the request level. To fix this, set a "max" timeout on the `HttpClient`, which can be infinite:

```
httpClient.Timeout = System.Threading.Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan;
```

Comment: As was mentioned in another answer, this can only reduce the time of cancellation. Therefore, if you plan on using this method, it might be best to set the default timeout to infinite (or some other amount you can be happy with), and plan on providing your own cancellation token to each and **every** request.

Comment: @Todd Menier: I follow your answer for a similar problem but I cannot solve it, maybe you can help me:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54326681/system-net-http-httpclient-not-respect-timeouts-and-use-everytime-the-default-va

Answer (score 14):

The accepted answer is great, but I wanted to give another scenario for anyone looking for this in the future. In my case, I was already using a CancellationTokenSource that would cancel its token when the user chose to cancel. So in that case you can still use this technique by using the CreateLinkedTokenSource method of CancellationTokenSource. So in my scenario the http operation will cancel either by the timeout or the user's intervention. Here's a sample:

```
public async static Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendRequest(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var ctsForTimeout = new CancellationTokenSource();
    ctsForTimeout.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    var cancellationTokenForTimeout = ctsForTimeout.Token;

    using (var linkedCts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken, cancellationTokenForTimeout))
    {
        try
        {
            return await httpClient.GetAsync("http://asdfadsf", linkedCts.Token);
        }
        catch
        {
            //just for illustration purposes
            if (cancellationTokenForTimeout.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("timeout");
            }
            else if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("other cancellation token cancelled");
            }
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using a `CancellationToken` perhaps from an async API endpoint, you can combine it with another `CancellationToken` using `CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource`.

Here's an example:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendRequestWithTimeout(HttpRequestMessage request, Timespan timeout, CancellationToken ct){
    var timeoutCt = new CancellationTokenSource(timeout).Token;
    var linkedCts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(ct, timeoutCt).Token;
    return await httpClient.SendAsync(request, linkedCts);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

.NET 6 (and later) now includes `Task.WaitAsync(TimeSpan)` method that you can use.

```csharp
    await httpClient.SendAsync(request).WaitAsync(TomeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
```

> Gets a Task that will complete when this Task completes or when the
> specified timeout expires.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitasync?view=net-8.0#system-threading-tasks-task-waitasync(system-timespan)

P.S. However, if you decide to use this workaround, **please** do have a look at this post by Andrew Lock **"Just because you stopped waiting for it, doesn't mean the Task stopped running"**

https://andrewlock.net/just-because-you-stopped-waiting-for-it-doesnt-mean-the-task-stopped-running/

After the timeout elapses - make sure you abort the request!

Comment: Any reason why this would be preferred to the accepted answer? (Just trying to decide which approach to use)

Comment: @jazza1000 (1) does not create a linked token (heavywait) (2) shorter code

Comment: I afraid `HttpClient` "default timeout will still cancel the operation after default 100 seconds even you set 5 minutes in `WaitAsync()`