# Flurl not respecting timeout setting

Tags: flurl

I am using flurl with a 5 second timeout in Xamarin Forms.

```
 flurlClient.Configure(settings => settings.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
 await flurlClient.Request("api", "ping", "phonehome").GetAsync();
```

When run on UWP, the timeout works fine.  However, iOS and Droid go a full minute despite having the 5 second setting set.

Any thoughts on how this can be fixed?

**UPDATE**

I was able to get the timeout to work by using the `.WithTimeout(seconds)` call.  However, I have to do this on every flurl request.  Not a huge deal, but not sure why the .Configure method doesn't work.

**UPDATE 2**

Here is what I see after implementing @ToddMenier's suggested changes.  The timeout is set to 5 seconds, but it takes over a minute to actually timeout.

[image]

Comment: What version of Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android are you on? The one "fancy" feature of the BCL that Flurl uses internally for settings is `[CallerMemberName]`. Supported platforms are listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute#applies-to).

Comment: ...although those have been part of .NET Standard since 1.0 so assuming those platforms implement it correctly, that's probably not it. You could narrow this down a bit by configuring `flurlClient` as you did above, use it to create a request like this: `var req = flurlClient.Request()`, then checking `req.Settings.Timeout` to see if the request correctly inherited the client-level setting.

Comment: @ToddMenier thanks for the suggestions.  I modified my code per those in UPDATE 2 above.  You can see the timeout is set to 5 seconds, but it still takes over a minute to actually timeout.  I am on VS 2019 16.3.8, Xamarin   16.3.0.278, Xamarin.Android SDK 10.0.6.2, Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK 13.6.0.12, Xamarin Forms 4.2.0.910310.

Comment: @ToddMenier my UPDATE 2 changes didn't save so I just added them back in.

Comment: I guess that proves the settings inheritance mechanism isn't the problem. All that happens in Flurl is a `CancellationToken` is added to the call. Try it with a raw `HttpClient` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46877380/62600). If that doesn't work at least it proves it's not Flurl-specific, which would allow you to reframe the question and hopefully open it up to a broader audience. (I'm not a Xamarin dev myself.)

Answer (score 0):

Same is working for me. Running on iPhone Simulator:

```
    private async void BtnTestFLUrl_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FlurlClient flurlClient = new FlurlClient("https://www.mocky.io/v2/5dc580f13200008200769b0f?mocky-delay=5000ms");
        flurlClient.Configure(settings => settings.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
        var result = await flurlClient.Request("").GetAsync();
    }
```